# How to check if there is a word in between two lines?

Tags: python, regex, text

I have a text file and I want check if there is a line with find_me after XXX 4 and before XXX 5.

```
>     """
>     XXX 1
>     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>     XXX 2
>     find_me "HELLO_1"
>     XXX 3
>     find_me "HELLO_2"
>     aaaaaaaaaaaaa
>     XXX 4
>     aaaaaaaaaaaaa
>     XXX 5
```

Attempt:

```
find_me = r'(?<=XXX 4)(.*)(?=XXX 5)'
tmp = re.search(find_me, text)

if check:
tmp2 = tmp.group()
print tmp2
```

Comment: Please add the code you've tried so far

Comment: @Emma - https://regex101.com/r/UUIh57/1

Comment: Can XXX followed by an other digits than 4 and 5 occur between XXX 4 and XXX 5? If not, try https://regex101.com/r/XUIAq8/1/

Answer (score 0):

This expression might work, not sure though:

```
(?<=XXX 4)[\s\S]*?find_me[\s\S]*?(?=XXX 5)
```

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"(?<=XXX 4)[\s\S]*?find_me[\s\S]*?(?=XXX 5)"

test_str = """
>     XXX 1
>     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>     XXX 2
>     find_me "HELLO_1"
>     XXX 3
>     find_me "HELLO_2"
>     aaaaaaaaaaaaa
>     XXX 4
>     aaaaaaaaaaaaa
>     find_me "HELLO_2"
>     XXX 5


>     XXX 1
>     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>     XXX 2
>     find_me "HELLO_1"
>     XXX 3
>     find_me "HELLO_2"
>     aaaaaaaaaaaaa
>     XXX 4
>     aaaaaaaaaaaaa
>     find_me "HELLO_2"
>     XXX 5
"""

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
['\n>     aaaaaaaaaaaaa\n>     find_me "HELLO_2"\n>     ', '\n>     aaaaaaaaaaaaa\n>     find_me "HELLO_2"\n>     ']
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mqmBb3/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/mqmBb3/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.